# How to test Servlet on Mockito?

Tags: java, servlets, mockito

I'm new to mokito, I'm trying to test my servlet who is responsible for registering the user. I'm trying to lock up the HttpRequestServlet but I always get ClassFormException. I can not understand why. How can this be fixed, can you tell? How it is possible to properly test a servlet and to mock HttpServletRequest?

```
@Mock
    private HttpServletRequest request = mock(HttpServletRequest.class); ;

    @After
    public void verifyRequest(){
        verify(request).getParameter(ConstantApp.RegistrationConstantField.GET_FIRST_NAME);
        verify(request).getParameter(ConstantApp.RegistrationConstantField.GET_LAST_NAME);
        verify(request).getParameter(ConstantApp.RegistrationConstantField.GET_LOGIN);
        verify(request).getParameter(ConstantApp.RegistrationConstantField.GET_EMAIL);
        verify(request, Mockito.atLeast(2)).getParameter(ConstantApp.RegistrationConstantField.GET_PASSWORD);
        verify(request).getParameter(ConstantApp.RegistrationConstantField.GET_CONFIRM_PASSWORD);
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldReturnTrue_WhenWeGetValidField() throws Exception{
        when(request.getParameter(ConstantApp.RegistrationConstantField.GET_FIRST_NAME)).thenReturn("Aloha");
        when(request.getParameter(ConstantApp.RegistrationConstantField.GET_LAST_NAME)).thenReturn("Dance");
        when(request.getParameter(ConstantApp.RegistrationConstantField.GET_LOGIN)).thenReturn("AlohaDance123");
        when(request.getParameter(ConstantApp.RegistrationConstantField.GET_EMAIL)).thenReturn("aloha.dance@gmail.com");
        when(request.getParameter(ConstantApp.RegistrationConstantField.GET_PASSWORD)).thenReturn("12345678Aa$");
        when(request.getParameter(ConstantApp.RegistrationConstantField.GET_CONFIRM_PASSWORD)).thenReturn("12345678Aa$");

        Validation validation = new Validation();
        Map<String, String> errorMap = validation.validate(new RegistrationInfoImpl(request));

        assertTrue(errorMap.isEmpty());
    }
```

My Exception:

```
   java.lang.ClassFormatError: Absent Code attribute in method that is not native or abstract in class file javax/servlet/ServletException

    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1975)
    at org.mockito.cglib.core.ReflectUtils.addAllMethods(ReflectUtils.java:349)
    at org.mockito.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.getMethods(Enhancer.java:427)
    at org.mockito.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.generateClass(Enhancer.java:457)
    at org.mockito.cglib.core.DefaultGeneratorStrategy.generate(DefaultGeneratorStrategy.java:25)
    at org.mockito.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator.create(AbstractClassGenerator.java:217)
    at org.mockito.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.createHelper(Enhancer.java:378)
    at org.mockito.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.createClass(Enhancer.java:318)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.cglib.ClassImposterizer.createProxyClass(ClassImposterizer.java:123)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.cglib.ClassImposterizer.imposterise(ClassImposterizer.java:57)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.cglib.ClassImposterizer.imposterise(ClassImposterizer.java:49)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.cglib.CglibMockMaker.createMock(CglibMockMaker.java:24)
    at org.mockito.internal.util.MockUtil.createMock(MockUtil.java:33)
    at org.mockito.internal.MockitoCore.mock(MockitoCore.java:59)
    at org.mockito.Mockito.mock(Mockito.java:1285)
    at org.mockito.Mockito.mock(Mockito.java:1163)
    at servlet.RegistrationServletTest.<init>(RegistrationServletTest.java:25)
```

Comment: It looks like you may not have all the needed dependencies defined. How does your pom.xml (or other build format you're using) file is looks like?

Comment: Could you please provide the following?: 1) the library and version of your servlet implementation 2) the version of Mockito 3) the version of the JDK  you are using

Comment: BTW If you use @Mock annotation you shouln't initialize the request with the Mockito.mock(..) function

Comment: Also, the "validation" class should be injected (and should be a field) with the @InjectMocks annotation. take a look at point 6 here: https://www.baeldung.com/mockito-annotations